# Products of spaces with an underlying free ultrafilter as topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, ultrafilters

If ${\cal U}$ is any ultrafilter on $\omega$, the pair $(\omega,{\cal U}\cup \{\emptyset\})$ is a connected topological space. Is there a non-principal ultrafilter ${\cal U}$ on $\omega$ such that we have $(\omega,{\cal U}\cup \{\emptyset\})\cong (\omega,{\cal U}\cup \{\emptyset\})^2$?

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth mentioning that the somewhat similar product of ultrafilters is mentioned in this post: [Product of ultrafilters, is it an ultrafilter?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/73237)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Note that in the space $X = (\omega, \mathcal{U}\cup\{\emptyset\})$, every set is either open or closed.  However in the space $X^2$, neither $\overline{\Delta} = \{(m,n) : n\ge m\}$ nor $\underline{\Delta} = \{(m,n) : n < m\}$ can be open, since neither of these sets contains a rectangle of the form $A\times B$ with $A,B\in\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Very nice argument -- it escaped me totally!